# Converting values inside constructor initialization list c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

Say I have a constructor that takes in a string type vector.
If one of the class member is not a string but instead a double, how would I go about converting the string vector element to double inside the constructor?

```
Foo::Foo(const std::vector<string>& v):
d(v[0].toDouble()){}
```

I am aware that toDouble() doesn't work in c++ I'm just putting it here as an example of what I want to do.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Answer (score 3):

This is not the only way to do it, of course. Using `std::stod()` would be one way, but in the event that you need to handle a conversion error, you have to do this in two steps:

```
Foo::Foo(const std::vector<string>& v) : d(convert(v[0]))
{
}
```

The second step would be this `convert()`, a private static method:

```
double Foo::convert(const std::string &s)
{
   std::istringstream i(s);
   double v;

   i >> v;
   if (i.fail())
   {
       // Figure out what to do, here
   }
   return v;
}
```

Your homework assignment here would be to figure out what to do if the conversion fails, and take appropriate action.